# Find max In array where items may be numbers or arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to find the maximum value in an array where each value may be either a positive number or another array of positive numbers. I have this, but I'm not sure how to deal with the nested arrays.

```
var array = [5, 8, 15, [10, 2, [6, 20, 1], 4, 13, [2, 11]]];
function findMax(arr) {
  var max = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // what if it's an array?
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max= arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
console.log(findLargest(array));
// answer should be 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function findMax(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.max(prev, Array.isArray(curr) ? findMax(curr) : curr), 0);
}
console.log(findMax(array));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just flatten it first?

```js
var array = [5, 8, 15, [10, 2, [6, 20, 1], 4, 13, [2, 11]]];
const findMax = arr => Math.max(...array.flat(Infinity));
console.log(findMax(array));
```

Comment: Actually the question said I couldn't flatten it :(

Comment: You should include all relevant restrictions in your question when you first post it, not after answers are posted